# Git not picking up change to database project's properties in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022, sql-server-data-tools

I am changing a setting in visual studio project but git does not seem to be picking it up?

I am right clicking my project (database project) in visual studio, clicked properties and changing a option in the Debug Menu (One highlighted in screenshot).

I rebuild the solution so am expecting git to pick up that something has changed but it does not. I wanted to check this change into version control as we have having release issues.

I would have thought it would be a gitignore issue but I do not ignore the .sqlproj file and I would expect this is the file that would change?

Would anyone know what file would be changed?

[image: Property being changed]

I tried including various files into source control so they were not ignored but cannot locate the file that would store this setting

Comment: Where are those settings stored? Which file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That setting isn't stored in the database project itself (`.sqlproj`), but in the associated per-user-settings file (`.sqlproj.user`):

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupScript>(Blank)</StartupScript>
    <StartAction>StartNone</StartAction>
    <BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>True</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The `*.user` files are excluded by the default Visual Studio `.gitIgnore` file.

If you want this setting to be stored in the git repository, you'll need to manually add it to the `.sqlproj` file by editing the project file's xml directly and adding:

```xml
    <BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>True</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
```

To any of the default property groups or to a new one.

To do so, unload the project:

[image: Unload project in the context menu of the solution explorer]

Then edit the project (if the XML view doesn't open automatically):
[image: Edit the project from the context menu in the solution explorer]

Add the property to the project file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>True</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <Name>Database1</Name>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectVersion>4.1</ProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{9b8b7b42-6d5c-4711-b7fa-567d2c0c6642}</ProjectGuid>
    <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql
```

Reload the project:

[image: Reload the project from the solution explorer]

The setting has now been lifted from the user settings to the project file and the change should show up in your git changes, ready to be committed:

[image]